# Is it possible to alternate the row colors in a SAP Fiori List?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to alternate the row colors in a sap.m.List. For sap.m.Table there is a property called "alternateRowColor" that can be set "true". Ist there something similar for a List? Inside the List I got items with ObjectListItems.

```
<List items="{/MonateSet}">
<items>
<ObjectListItem title="{name}" number="{summe}" numberUnit="EUR" type="Active" press="onListItemPress"> </ObjectListItem>
</items>
</List>
```

Answer (score -1):

I could solve the issue by seting `mode="SingleSelectMaster"` property of the list.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question